# How to detect if running ipython qtconsole?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

The IPython notebook and Qt console both support displaying rich representations of objects.  This is done by defining, for example, a `_repr_html_` method.

The problem is that these two render the HTML differently.  Is there a way for me to detect whether running under `ipython qtconsole` so that I can use a more basic set of HTML?  Preferably a documented way that is not likely to break in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Doing color in IPython terminal requires calling in to windows DLL's, but the color in qtconsole seems to support the linux based escape sequences....anyway. here's what I have found. Its ugly...but it will at least tell you terminal vs. qtconsole...Oh, and I haven't tried with the notebook:

```
import __main__
if hasattr(__main__,"get_ipython"): 
   import IPython.kernel.zmq.zmqshell as z
   if isinstance(get_ipython(), z.ZMQInteractiveShell):
       print 'yep...its qtconsole'
```